# How to detect buffer overflow in Godot WebSocketPeer?

Tags: websocket, godot

Is it possible to detect a buffer overflow in a WebSocketPeer in Godot? Overflows seem to log console outputs, but I'm not sure how to react to overflows from within the Godot game itself.

Digging through the Godot source files, It seems like in `packet_peer.cpp`, `_poll_buffer` can return an error if there is an overflow. However this is a private method, and when it's used elsewhere in `packet_peer.cpp`, the returned Errors aren't propagated upward to a public-facing API.